# Apply an R function over multiple arrays, returning an array of the same size

Tags: arrays, r, plyr

I have two arrays of 2x2 matrices, and I'd like to apply a function over each pair of 2x2 matrices. Here's a minimal example, multiplying each matrix in A by its corresponding matrix in B:

```
A <- array(1:20, c(5,2,2))
B <- array(1:20, c(5,2,2))
n <- nrow(A)
# Desired output: array with dimension 5x2x2 that contains 
# the product of each pair of 2x2 matrices in A and B.
C <- aperm(sapply(1:n, function(i) A[i,,]%*%B[i,,], simplify="array"), c(3,1,2))
```

This takes two arrays, each with 5 2x2 matrices, and multiplies each pair of 2x2 matrices together, with the desired result in C.

My current code is this ugly last line, using sapply to loop through the first array dimension and pull out each 2x2 matrix separately from A and B. And then I need to permute the array dimensions with aperm() in order to have the same ordering as the original arrays (sapply(...,simplify="array") indexes each 2x2 matrix using the third dimension rather than the first one).

Is there a nicer way to do this? I hate that ugly function(i) in there, which is really just a way of faking a for loop. And the aperm() call makes this much less readable. What I have now works fine; I'm just searching for something that feels more like idiomatic R.

mapply() will take multiple lists or vectors, but it doesn't seem to work with arrays. aaply() from plyr is also close, but it doesn't take multiple inputs. The closest I've come is to use abind() with aaply() to pack A and B into one array work with 2 matrices at once, but this doesn't quite work (it only gets the first two entries; somewhere my indexing is off):

```
aaply(.data=abind(A,B,along=0), 1, function(ab) ab[1,,]%*%ab[2,,])
```

And this isn't exactly cleaner or clearer anyway!

I've tried to make this a minimal example, but my real use case requires a more complicated function of the matrix pairs (and I'd also love to scale this up to more than two arrays), so I'm looking for something that will generalize and scale.

Answer (score 2):

```
D <- aaply(abind(A, B, along = 4), 1, function(x) x[,,1] %*% x[,,2])
```

This is a working solution using `abind` and `aaply`.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a for loop is the easiest to follow.  It also generalizes and scales:

```
n <- nrow(A)
C <- A
for(i in 1:n) C[i,,] <- A[i,,] %*% B[i,,]
```

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned this as another obvious solution. I was hoping for a functional approach, but R seems to have much less infrastructure for doing functional things with arrays than it does with lists. I'd like to avoid looping to make this scale better to more complicated expressions of A and B, so I don't have all the indexing everywhere.

Comment: without much loss of readability, you could write this loop in RcppArmadillo, it's pretty similar to R/matlab for matrix algebra and indexing.

Comment: Looping should scale just as well as `sapply`.  I have seen situations where looping was the fastest solution. Its easy enough to hide the indexing in a function: `combine <- function(A, B, FUN = '%*%') { ... }` If you are worried about speed then put the 5 dimension at the end instead of the beginning.  Also instead of using arrays you could use a list of matrices.

Answer (score 0):

R's infrastructure for lists is much better (it seems) than for arrays, so I could also approach it by converting the arrays into lists of matrices like this:

```
A <- alply(A, 1, function(a) matrix(a, ncol=2, nrow=2))
B <- alply(A, 1, function(a) matrix(a, ncol=2, nrow=2))
mapply(function(a,b) a%*%b, A, B, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

I think this is more straightforward than what I have above, but I'd still love to hear better ideas.